# Copying values in one row to another in R

Tags: r, loops, row, copying

I'm trying to copy values from one row to another specified row in the corresponding column that has a value of NA.

In this case--if the values in Row 1 are NA, they should copy values from Row 5. If the values in Row 2 are NA, they should copy values in Row 6.

This is the sample dataframe:

```
      Name1   Name2   
   1  NA      NA      
   2  4       NA      
   3  5       8         
   4  2       5     
   5  3       6    
   6  4       7  
   7  5       8
```

This is the intended output:

```
      Name1   Name2   
   1  3       6   
   2  4       7   
   3  5       8         
   4  2       5     
   5  3       6    
   6  4       7  
   7  5       8
```

I'm able to make this happen by writing an if statement for each cell of the data frame, but it's not ideal. (Based on the example dataframe--the below code would have to be essentially repeated four times.)

Example:

```
if (is.na(df[1,]$Name1){
     df[1,]$Name1 = df[5,]$Name1
}
```

How do you write a more efficient code for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the condition, loop through the column, get the index of NA elements ('i1') and `replace` the values of the column based on the 'i1' using the values of the column where the index is added with 4 and assign the output back to the dataset

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) {
                   i1 <- which(is.na(x))
                   replace(x, i1, x[i1+4])
 })
df1
#  Name1 Name2
#1     3     6
#2     4     7
#3     5     8
#4     2     5
#5     3     6
#6     4     7
#7     5     8
```

NOTE: It is not clear about the condition when the `NA` values after the 4th row in each column

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to use the tidyverse you could do something like this.

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(purrr)

df <- tibble(Name1 = c(NA, 1:6), Name2 = c(NA, NA, 1:5))

replace_var_lead <- function(var) {

  tmp_df <- tibble(rep = lead(var, n = 4),
         var = var) %>% 
    rowwise %>% 
    mutate(var = var %>% replace_na(rep))

  return(tmp_df$var)
}

df %>% 
  map_df(replace_var_lead)
```

Note: This has the same weakness as the answer using base R. The replacement may also be NA.